# Html5 audio/video playback not synced on Chrome and Firefox

Tags: asp.net, html5-video, h.264, aac

We are building a completely web-based system for recording video questions and answers and due to a number of details that I <strike>don't fully understand</strike> can't get into our video recorder is a flash element that records to an mp4 with h.264 and Speex codecs. The video then gets re-encoded with the AAC audio codec.

We have an html5 video player with flash fallback (videojs) that works well, but only in Internet Explorer. In Chrome and Firefox, the audio starts playing about a second into the the track, while the video plays normally. It does not appear that the flash fallback is being used for any of the browsers I am testing  in (IE11, FF and Chrome), so I don't think it's a flash issue.
The re-encoded videos have no synchronization issues when played from the desktop, so they are being recorded correctly.

This is the video player:

```
<video id="html5video" runat="server" preload="metadata" controls height="240">
            <!-- re-encoded version -->
    <source src="http://<% =VideoServer%>/content/<% =VideoUrl%>_360p.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
            <!-- original version -->
    <source src="http://<% =VideoServer%>/content/<% =VideoUrl%>.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
</video>
```

According to [this documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Supported_media_formats#Browser_compatibility), Chrome and Firefox should not have any issues with h.264 and AAC in MP4.
Unfortunately re-encoding to completely different video and audio codecs is not an option, which is why we wanted the flash fallback in the first place.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Supported_media_formats To avoid patent issues, support for MPEG 4, H.264, MP3 and AAC is not built directly into Firefox on desktop and mobile (Android and Firefox OS). Instead it relies on support from the OS or hardware (the hardware also needs to be able to support the profile used to encode the video, in the case of MP4). Firefox desktop supports these formats on the following platforms:

Comment: I am aware of that, however all major operating systems (with the exception of OS X which we are not testing on) support those codecs. Besides, the issue also occurs in Chrome, which supports those codecs fully out of the box.